garbage on UI when cobalt launch Youtube
I am currently porting Cobalt to our embedded linux system, and I have successfully displayed the YouTube interface. However, when playing videos, sometimes garbage appears after clicking the settings button, as shown in the attachment. Could you please advise on what might be causing this issue or suggest any debugging methods? Thanks
I try to dump the texture data, garbage exist on it.
